# django calculate object position in the list

Tags: python, django

I have a list which contain objects from the model. List is generated from queryset and ordered by object ID. Now how can I easily find position of the specific object in the list? For example list have a 100 object and targeted object is on the position 22. How can I know that? I would like to create filter and to pass list and object as data to it from the template.

```
mylist = (obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 ...)
target_obj = some_object


myfilter(mylist, taget_obj):
    ...
    return position
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way work for me and it is very easy to use.

```
< list >.index(< object >)
```

Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is object. It is an error if there is no such item.

Answer (score 0):

You can `enumerate` over the list, and find the position once you get the object you are after:

```
for key, item in enumerate(some_list):
   if item == target:
       return key
```